# Manually coding MVC Views vs. asp:ServerControls

Tags: model-view-controller, controls, view

I barely got into ASP.Net webforms when MVC came out, and now I'm ready to try it out. But, I want to clarify something to be sure I understand the View coding in ASP.Net MVC...

I've heard that you must hand-code all the HTML in the View layouts, and that you cannot use server controls for this. Now, I like the way you can use the asp:ListView to present a list of data in webforms, and I've made heavy use of the SelectedItemTemplate and the concept of SelectedItem as a whole. So, I fear a big headache in having have to handle all that output yourself, versus letting the server controls do it. Same goes for DataGridView and the Select, Edit, Delete commadds that come with that server control.

In a particular case I am brainstorming over, I have Customer names displayed in a asp:ListView, and then when you click on a Customer name, it uses the SelectedItemTemplate that expands within the ListView to highlight that row and show more details about that particular Customer (right in the ListView).

I'd love to see some sample asp.Net MVC view code that shows how to handle this commone UI presentation technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some good GridView for ASP.NET MVC

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MVCFlexigrid.aspx

http://www.reconstrukt.com/ingrid/example1.html